# How to commit in git and completely overwrite without any merging?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm not sure how to do this. I am the only person working on my project. When I need help, I commit and push my changes to github only in order to get help from people who need to see my code in its current state. After pushing to github, I want to roll back that last commit so that I can see the differences between the last real commit and the current code while I continue working on the changes. I'm using Visual Studio Code and its Undo Last Commit menu item, whatever git command that runs.

When I do this, I get lots of merge conflict problems. This doesn't seem right because I am the only one working on my project. It seems to be treating my previous commit as the work of someone else and negotiating the differences between that and what I have at the moment.

I don't want git to do any comparison with the last commit, but rather just accept my new code. How can I do this?

EDIT: Updated last sentence for clarity. Changed "it" to "git".

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the first paragraph you write: "I want to roll back that last commit so that I can see the differences between the last real commit and the current code while I continue working on the changes." In the last paragraph you say "I don't want it to do any comparison with the last commit, but rather just accept my new code. How can I do this?" My recommendation would be that you take some time to understand git and learn how to use the command line interface https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: Try `git reset --soft @~` or `git reset @~`, depending on what you want left staged for your next commit.

Comment: @jthill I think this is probably part of the answer to my question. Could you flesh that out a bit? There's likely a few git commands required to commit, push and rollback changes to put my changes on github for others to see and then put my local code back to what it was.

Comment: I think it is part of the answer, but you're using a GUI and its "friendly" menus that kick off God knows what, leaving me as ignorant of what it's actually doing as you are.

Comment: I'm happy to use the command line too. The editor doesn't prohibit that. Do you need any clarification about what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Since communication isn't a problem, you're doing first-draft work and are soliciting comment, not publishing for use, you have a completely free hand with what you create and push.  `git reset` is used to reset ancestry, so after pushing one of these for-comment snapshots do `git reset --soft @~` or just `git reset @~`, the difference being that the soft reset leaves the index alone.  Both of those excise the current branch tip from the history you're constructing with your commits.  Next time you want to push a snapshot you'll either have to force-replace (`git push -f`) the old one or give it a new name, since the Git there will notice the new commit is missing the history that's already tyere.